# Printing duplicates from a list in Java

Tags: java, collections

Really basic question:

I have items being added to some collection (I don't mind which yet) and I want a method which prints the items in groups e.g.

```
public enum Animal{
COW("cow"), PIG("pig"), SHEEP("sheep");

private String itemName;

public String toString() {
    return itemName;
}
}

public class Farm {

private ArrayList<Animal> animals= new ArrayList<>();

animals.add{Animal.COW} 
animals.add{Animal.COW}
animals.add{Animal.PIG}
animals.add{Animal.COW}
animals.add{Animal.SHEEP}
animals.add{Animal.PIG}

public String animalList {

...
}
```

animalList output: 3 x cow, 2 x pig, 1 x sheep

What's the best way to do this? Would a map be better instead of a list i.e. a map from each animal to the amount of this animal? But then it might be hard to add a new animal to the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `HashMap` is the better choice,but use your `Animal` as a `key` here

```
    HashMap<Animal, Integer> animalHashMap=new HashMap<Animal, Integer>();
    animalHashMap.put(Animal.COW, 3);
    animalHashMap.put(Animal.SHEEP, 10);
    animalHashMap.put(Animal.PIG, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Multiset(Bag) e.g. from the guava collection: [Multiset](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset)

You just add the elements (animals) and can query for each animal how many times it is in the set.

Usage:

```
    Multiset<String> animals = HashMultiset.create();
    animals.add("cow");
    animals.add("cow");
    animals.add("cow");
    animals.add("pig");
    animals.add("pig");
    animals.add("sheep");

    for (String a : animals)
        System.out.println(animals.count(a) + "x " + a);
```

Comment: This is a link only answer !

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do

The idea of a `ArrayList` is to keep items in order. Then if its a requirement then you should keep using it and use another algorithm to count them.

But if you dont want any of those details you can use something like a `MultiMap` (not native java). Or you can create one of your own.

As you specified in the title, what i would do is i'll have a `Map<Object,Integer>` and I check if the map contains object, then i increase the integer value. Then i can get the answer finally. (as shown in code by @TAsk)

Comment: I think you mean requirement, not retirement :)

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you can stream the animals and count them:

```
Map<Animal, Long> summary = animals.stream().collect(groupingBy(a -> a, counting()));
```

which requires the following imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question you don't need to keep track of each element's order so you don't have to use an `ArrayList` for example. 
You can simply use `EnumMap` with `Integer` as value:

```
EnumMap map = new EnumMap<Animal, Integer>();
```

You can then check for each element if it exist in your map and if so increase the corresponding value otherwise add it with value 1.

`EnumMap` is

> a specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys.

and it's obviously more efficient than `ArrayList`. Unless you want some other functionality you don't mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a self-contained example, Java 5+ compatible (within a `Main` class)...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    animals.add(Animal.COW);
    animals.add(Animal.COW);
    animals.add(Animal.PIG);
    animals.add(Animal.COW);
    animals.add(Animal.SHEEP);
    animals.add(Animal.PIG);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("animals contains... \n");
    for (Animal a:Animal.values()) {
        sb
            .append(a.name())
            .append(" --> ")
            .append(
                Collections.frequency(animals, a)
            )
            .append(" instances.\n");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}

static enum Animal {
    COW("cow"), PIG("pig"), SHEEP("sheep");

    private String itemName;

    Animal(String name) {
        itemName = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return itemName;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
animals contains... 
COW --> 3 instances.
PIG --> 2 instances.
SHEEP --> 1 instances.
```

**Note**

The main thing to notice here is to use `Collections.frequency` to count the instances of the same element (`o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e)`) within the `Collection`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Collections.frequency()`. You can store it in a map like this

```
Map< Animal,Integer> countAnimals = new HasMap< Animal,Integer>();
// Initializing all the animal count to zero
for(Animal animal: Animal.values()){
    countAnimals(animal,0);
}
// counting for all animals
for(Animal animal:myListOfAnimals){ // in you case myListOfAnimals is animals
    countAnimals.put(animal, countAnimals.get(animal)++);
}
```

Now the countAnimals map has all the counts.